# Get a value from a selected OrgChart node (Google orgchart)

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, google-visualization

I am trying to retrieve a value i.e. the name Mike from a selected node of a Google `orgchart`.
At the moment I show on the alert the ID of the employee "`v`", but not the name "`f`". I have tried to modify the select event but no luck.

Any ideas how to show a specific value from the selected node?

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4dnxvenw/2/)

```
function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
    data.addColumn('string', 'Rank');
    data.addColumn('string', 'ToolTip');

         // For each orgchart box, provide the name, manager, and tooltip to show.
    data.addRows([
      [{ "v": '1', f: 'Mike<div style="color:red; font-style:italic">President</div>' }, '', 'The President'],
      [{ "v": '2', f: 'Jim<div style="color:red; font-style:italic">vice</div>' }, '1', 'VICE'],
      [{ "v": '3', f: 'Three<div style="color:red; font-style:italic">vice</div>' }, '1', 'VICE'],
      [{ "v": '4', f: 'Four<div style="color:red; font-style:italic">vice</div>' }, '3', 'VICE'],
      [{ "v": '5', f: 'Five<div style="color:red; font-style:italic">vice</div>' }, '3', 'VICE']
    ]);

    // Create the chart.
    var chart = new google.visualization.OrgChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    // Draw the chart, setting the allowHtml option to true for the tooltips.
    chart.draw(data, { allowHtml: true });

    // When the orgchart is selected
    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function () {
        // alert('sel');
        this.blur;
        var selectedItem = chart.getSelection()[0];
        if (selectedItem) {
            var selectedValue = data.getValue(selectedItem.row, 0);
            console.log('The user selected ' + selectedValue);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the `getFormattedValue` method...

```
    if (selectedItem) {
        var selectedValue = data.getFormattedValue(selectedItem.row, 0);
        console.log('The user selected ' + selectedValue);
    }
```

`v:` -- value - `getValue(rowIndex, columnIndex)`

`f:` -- formatted value - `getFormattedValue(rowIndex, columnIndex)`

---

other methods --> [DataTable methods](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#methods)

Comment: It works. What if I want to get the Rank's or Tooltip's value?

Comment: just change the column index, second argument to method -- currently using `0`

Comment: Great. It works. Previously, I was trying to change the column index on the getValue but I believe via that function the column index is always null.

Comment: right, the `selectedItem` will not give you the column, because there is only one series of data -- it is typically used with the `'corechart'` package...